# jQuery .click() - need to determine where mouse was pressed, not released

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I have a simple popup plugin that I'm using, and it closes itself automatically when you click outside of the popup, via this code:

`scroll-element`, `contentSelector`, and `originalElement` are the elements allowed to be clicked, a click on any other item will close the popup. This is fine, but I want it to close only on clicks where the mouse was *pressed and released* outside of the popup.

```
    $(parentSelector).unbind('click').click(function(event) {
        if( !$(event.target).closest(contentSelector).length && !$(event.target).closest('.scroll-element').length && !$(event.target).closest(originalElement).length ) {
            if( $(contentSelector).is(":visible") ) {
                destroyPopup();
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is, if you click inside the popup but drag your mouse outside of the popup, then release it, the popup closes when it should stay open in this case.

Here is a sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zb603hd5/

In the fiddle, try clicking the white area and releasing the click in the white area; the popup will stay open.

Now try clicking in the white area but holding your click and dragging your mouse outside of the popup and releasing it, the popup will close. I do not want this to happen. I want *any* click that originated in the popup to not close it.

The reason this is an issue is because sometimes scrollbars get attached to this popup and if a user is dragging the scrollbar and lets go of their mouse outside of the popup it closes when they just wanted to scroll.

Is there anyway to determine from the `event` parameter passed to the `.click()` function that would allow me to determine if the click is pressed inside of these elements instead of released by default?

Comment: A "click" is defined as a mouse down followed by mouse up *on the same element*. But clicks bubble, and the popup is a child element of the full-page background div. So can you add a click handler to the popup that stops propagation? Then leave the click handler on the outer div to do the close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dont use .unbind('click').click();

instead use

```
$(parentSelector).off('mousedown').on('mousedown',function(event){
    //Rest remains the same
});
```

Now mouseup will not be fired on click and drag outside your target.

Heres the updated fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/anubhabB/4x661z6j/